# How to make menus, footer, sidebars multi language

Tags: theme-development, multisite, themes

I am totally new to WordPress. I recently encountered this problem. I want to make my site 3 languages. I searched a lot and understand how to change the posts and pages languages with plugin, but the trouble is that when I choose other language, my whole theme (footer, menus, sidebar) are in basic language.

How I can solve this?

In some sites I saw a suggestion of Poedit; but the phrases in it I guess is irrelevant to what I have in footer and theme stuff.

So should I make different sites? Please help me.

By the way my theme name is Di Business.

Answer (score 0):

Most decent themes are already set up for translation and if so, poedit will certainly let you translate all the theme elements. If you don't want to get your hands dirty using poedit, there's a nice plugin called Loco Translate which allows you to do it much more simply. Contact your theme developers and ask them if the theme is prepared for localization first.